# Upgrade java applications from old to a newest version

Tags: java, compilation, upgrade

I have a doubt about java upgrading

I have applications running in java 6, for example.

And I wanto to upgrade my java to a 7 or 8

**My doubt is**: What is the best way to upgrade mi current java version?
Or how can I do it?

***This applications currently are productive***, so this means I has to upgrade the java version ***witouth affectate it***.

I'm very confused about this, hope you can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only one way to do it:

1. Upgrade the JVM
2. Recompile the code and fix any errors that the JVM complains about.
3. Regression test the code running under the new JVM and make sure the functionality is unchanged.
4. Take the opportunity to see if there are any advantages to adding new features (e.g. java.time package, lambdas, java.util.function package, etc.)

No one should be running on any JVM other than 8 or 9.  JDKs older than 8 have passed the end of their support lives.  They are not getting any more security patches.

You are making the excuse that everyone tries when faced with currency issues: "The code is working fine.  Why change it?"

Unfortunately there's a price to falling behind.

I'd advise you to upgrade as soon as possible.  Stop the excuses.

JDK 9 is the current version.  Current or current-1 is usually acceptable; current-3 is not.

Comment: *"No one should be running on any JVM other than 8"* Are you saying that no one should be using Java 9?

Comment: @duffymo

Thanks a lot dude, and yes I know the risks about had an old JVM, lower than 8, and your answer is too much useful, Your "general steps" as a guide

Again thanks a lot.

Comment: @Andreas, I think that refers to older versions, wich no passed the end of their support lives, in this case Java 8 still has support...

Comment: @CésarSánchez Answer say "**any** JVM other than 8", so that includes 9. I don't think duffymo intended to say you can't use 9, but that is what the answer is currently saying.

Comment: @Andreas - no, but I figure that it's a lot to ask of somebody who's still using JDK 6 to jump to 9.  Current or current-1 is usually acceptable.  Current-3 is not.